# Web UI to manage computer machines in the network

Tags: ssh, monitoring, webui

I'm looking for a platform with Web UI access that allows me to do the following:

Maintain a list of computers and add / remove based on their IP address.

Provide the SSH information for each computer machine.

Monitor if the machines are up ( ping ? )

Restart the machines with a web UI using the ssh information on the backend of the application.

I'm close to start making such an app myself since I can't seem to find anything close to that  in the internet. Any clues if such an application exists ?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at MeshCentral: https://meshcentral.com/  - you can add systems that you are managing and do some remote operations.

http://info.meshcentral.com/:  Meshcentral is open source and is both a peer-to-peer technology with a wide array of uses and web service that is targeted for remote monitoring and management of computers and devices. Users can manage all their devices from a single web site, no matter the location of the computers or if they are behind routers or proxies.

If you are looking for source code you could take a look at the "Open Manageabilty Developer's Toolkit" http://opentools.homeip.net/open-manageability.  This tool was built for managing systems with Intel Active Management Technology, but it does a lot of what you are looking for. You can download the source and see if you can use any of it if you decide to write your own UI.